# angular trustAsHtml not reinserting content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I have 2 divs on a page. When user clicks `button1` an `iframe` is loaded into `div1` and the same is true for `button2` and `div2`. The `iframes` are loaded through ajax and get trusted through the `$sce.trustAsHtml`. the html itself looks like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="video.trustediframe"></div>
```

This will be the result:

```
<div ng-bind-html="video.trustediframe"><iframe id="iframe1"></iframe></div>
```

Everything works and I can see the video, but when the user clicks `button2` I would like to close the feed to the first video and remove the `iframe` so I do `angular.element('#iframe1').remove()`. Now once the user clicks on `button1` again the `iframe` wont get loaded do the DOM again although the `div` with the `ng-bind-html="video.trustediframe"` is still in place.

I've tried reassigning the `video.trustediframe` variable(which is a function as `$sce.trustAsHtml` returns a function) and then doing `$scope.$apply` but that didn't help reinserting the `iframe`. Are there any other approaches can I use to get this behaviour right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the desired behaviour by keeping track of the currently active player. 
So with `<div ng-if="video.isPlaying" ng-bind-html="video.trustediframe"> </div>` I have only one active player per page and whenever the user switches between different tabs the previous player gets removed from dom.